# How to perform conditional arithmetic operations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've following schema

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxx"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-06-29T13:10:36.659+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-29T08:06:51.264+0000"), 
    "payments" : [
        {
            "paymentId" : "xxxxx", 
            "paymentType" : "charge", 
            "paymentCurrency" : "PKR", 
            "paymentMode" : "cash", 
            "paymentTotal" : 13501.88, 
            "penalties" : 100
        }, 
        {
            "paymentId" : "ccccc", 
            "paymentType" : "refund", 
            "paymentCurrency" : "PKR", 
            "paymentMode" : "", 
            "paymentTotal" : 13061.879999999997, 
            "penalties" : 430.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all paymentTotal sum if paymentType is 'charge' else subtract the paymentTotal from the sum if paymentType is other than charge, i.e refund also subtract penalties from total sum

I've tried following query which is not working giving me syntax error like,

```
A syntax error was detected at the runtime. Please consider using a higher shell version or use the syntax supported by your current shell.
```

xxx

> Blockquote

```
db.getCollection("booking").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            createdAt : {
            "$gte":ISODate("2022-06-28"),
            "$lte":ISODate("2022-06-30"),
        }
      }
    },
    {$unwind: '$payments'}, 
    {
        "$group":{
            "_id" : "$_id",
            "total" : {
                     $sum: "$payments.paymentTotal"
                }
            },
     },
     {
        $project :
        {
            "grandTotal":{
                $cond:{
                    if:{$eq:["$payments.paymentType", "charge"]},
                    then:{$add : {"$total,$payments.paymentTotal"}},
                    else:{ $subtract: {"$total,$payments.paymentTotal"}}
                }
            }
        }
     }
    
]);
```

I've tried, Condition and Switch statements but both are not working, or maybe I'm using them wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` for it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-06-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2022-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      grandTotal: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$payments",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$eq: ["$$this.paymentType", "charge"]},
              {$add: ["$$this.paymentTotal", "$$value"]},
              {$subtract: ["$$value", "$$this.paymentTotal"]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/majJmgkjdqC)

Comment: Hi @nimrod I'm having this issue while running this query, $reduce requires that 'input' be an array  , found: {0: {paymentId: \"1010\", paymentType: \"charge\", paymentCurrency: \"PKR\", paymentTotal: 126.6}, 1: {paymentId: \"321\", paymentType: \"refund\", paymentCurrency: \"PKR\", paymentTotal: 87}, 2: {paymentId: \"123\", paymentType: \"refund\", paymentCurrency: \"PKR\", paymentTotal: 10}, 3: {paymentId: \"432\", paymentType: \"charge\", paymentCurrency: \"PKR\", paymentTotal: 191.95}}"

Comment: In your example it is an array. Are you now saying it is an object, with keys that are the index?

Comment: If this is the case, use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVvSUMZgXgs)

Comment: My structure is same as I posted above but don't know why it's giving this error, btw I tried updated query and now it's giving following error. ----------- Command failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'' on server

Comment: Hi @nimrod could you please have a look on the following query what's wrong with it, I tried to resolve the above problem with different approach because although your provided solution is correct but don't know why it's not working in my project https://mongoplayground.net/p/LH64n-uHMEd

Comment: Try this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bqqH8Q1Kacy. Why do you say it is not working for you?

Comment: In your query you are using `$add` incorrectly. You need to provide an array to it

Comment: issue is very strange, when I run this query on my mongoshell it's showing me this error 

`'$reduce requires that 'input' be an array, found: {0: {paymentId: "123", paymentType: "charge",  paymentMode: "cash", paymentTotal: 126.6}`

but when I try to use objectToArray it's showing this error

`'$objectToArray requires a document input, found: array' on server `

Comment: thanks @nimrod, your answer helped me a lot to solve this problem, there was a wrong entry in my db which was causing this issue, I just deleted it and problem solved.

Comment: I've another issue now, all values coming as negative after placing this part to add penalties and refund amount to subtract it from total I placed this code in subtract, {
                $subtract: [                 
                  {
                    $add: [
                      "$$this.penalties",
                      "$$this.paymentTotal"
                    ]
                  },
                   "$$value"
                ]
              }
it's giving exact value but with negative sign.

Comment: Please share a mongodb palyground example

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/UdQpe28nHLp please have look at this, it's converting positive value to negative and vice versa.

Comment: Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XlyD9QMYEOk) out. Found the problem. You misplaced the `$$value` in the `$subtract` part

Comment: thanks, I found the solution already I was using $$this.v.paymentTotal which was wrong, I just need to use $$this.paymentTotal without index(v). thanks again for your help, appreciated.

Comment: Hi nimrod, could you please check why the result of first calculation is null, https://mongoplayground.net/p/LRsgt38U6I5 , when there is no penalty exist it gives null.

Comment: It has no penalties. Use `$ifNull`, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hHaMkvRwBQb)

Comment: thanks man it solved my problem, I was dam'n sure to use ifNull but couldn't figure it out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple math:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         grandTotal: {
            $map: {
               input: "$payments",
               in: {
                  $multiply: [
                     "$$this.paymentTotal",
                     { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.paymentType", "charge"] }, 1, -1] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { grandTotal: { $sum: "$grandTotal" } } }
])
```

Comment: Hi Wernfried, I'm getting following error while running your query in studio3T 
Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'' on server

Comment: The full response is:
{ 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1657706774, 1), 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'", 
    "code" : 40324.0, 
    "codeName" : "Location40324", 
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1657706774, 1), 
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "sjihuei8uy4uio96qZ6v2fXCA="), 
            "keyId" : NumberLong(7099315369575186433)
        }
    }
}

Comment: `$set` was introduced in MongoDB version 4.2 Use `$addFields` which is an alias for it (and what you would easily find in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/)).